# kde5 breeze-dark theme and kde icons not working in i3wm

Tags: kde, plasma, i3

I have selected breeze dark color for KDE applications via `systemsettings5`. When i run plasma, the dark thems applies properly, but when I run i3 it shows white theme. Can KDE themes be applied to KDE apps when running in non-kde windows managers?

[image: systemsettings5]

[image: breeze-dark-theme]

[image: breeze-dark-colors]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had similar problems and found [this somewhat related bugtracker entry](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/46093). There doesn't seem to be a convincing solution, I work around this by faking my desktop environment to be KDE. Give adding `XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=KDE` to your `.xprofile` a try and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks, I had to use the following in .profile to make it work:
```
if [[ $DESKTOP_SESSION=~"^i3.*$" ]]; then
    #export DESKTOP_SESSION="gnome"
    export DESKTOP_SESSION="kde"
    export XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP="KDE"
fi
```

Answer (score 5):

Set `QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME="qt5ct"` and`QT_PLUGIN_PATH=$HOME/.kde4/lib/kde4/plugins/:/usr/lib/kde4/plugins/`

Use `qt5ct` to set a theme.

I set it like that in my `.xprofile`:

```
if [ "$XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP" = "i3" ]; then
    export QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME="qt5ct"
    export QT_PLUGIN_PATH=$HOME/.kde4/lib/kde4/plugins/:/usr/lib/kde4/plugins/
fi
```

Answer (score 4):

The solution by @Horus is also covered in the Arch Linux wiki: [Configuration of Qt5 apps under environments other than KDE Plasma](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Qt#Configuration_of_Qt5_apps_under_environments_other_than_KDE_Plasma)

> Another solution is provided by the `qt5ct` package, which provides a DE independent Qt5 QPA and a configuration utility. After installing the package, run `qt5ct` to set an icon theme, and set the environment variable `QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME="qt5ct"` so that the settings are picked up by Qt applications. Alternatively, use `--platformtheme qt5ct` as argument to the Qt5 application.
>
> To automatically set `QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME` for user session, add the following line to `~/.xprofile`.
>
> ```
> [ "$XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP" = "KDE" ] || [ "$XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP" = "GNOME" ] || export QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME="qt5ct"
> ```

Comment: This answer was much easier to understand than Horus'.